# Why is CAS(Compare and Swap) atomic?

Tags: operating-system, compare-and-swap

I know CAS is a well-known atomic operation. But I struggle to see why it must be atomic. Take the sample code below as an example. After `if (*accum == *dest)`, if another thread jumps in and succeed to modify the `*dest` first, then switch back to the previous thread and it proceeds to `*dest = newval;`. Wouldn't that lead to a failure?

Is there something I am missing? Is there some mechanism that would prevent the above scenario from happening?

Any discussions would be greatly appreciated!

```
bool compare_and_swap(int *accum, int *dest, int newval)
{
  if (*accum == *dest) {
      *dest = newval;
      return true;
  } else {
      *accum = *dest;
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Often people use example code that is not atomic to describe what a CPU does atomically with a single instruction; because it's easier to see how it would work (and because a single `cmpxchg` instruction doesn't tell you much about how it works).

The code you've shown is like that (not atomic, to help understand how it works).

Comment: I looked into the implementations of Java's atomic constructs, which utilizes some methods like `compareAndSet(current, next)` or `getAndAddLong(this,valueOffset, 1L)`. I couldn't find the implementations of these methods, but I suppose they perform atomically. Do you think that these methods are special methods that directly utilize the hardware to perform atomic operations?

Comment: @XinyuCao: I don't know what "atomic" actually means for Java. Because it (literally) creates its own virtual machine, it can emulate "atomic" operations by wrapping them in a spinlock and doing "not atomic" instructions in that spinlock's critical section; which would make it "atomic from Java's perspective" and "not atomic from CPU's perspective". For performance, I'd expect that it tries to use the CPU's atomic instructions where possible. For portability, I'd expect it to work even if the CPU doesn't have any atomic instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I had this question,too.This kind of things couldn't happen. The function that you wrote is an abstract operation of CPU, and the impletement is atomatic in real. U can google the key words of "cmpxchg" and will get the answer you find.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code can lead to pitfalls that you mentioned as it looks from the outside. However, if we look at how it is compiled, it will lead to a `cmpxchg` command, which will be executed atomically by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As a computer science concept compare and swap HAS to be implemented atomically because of what it is designed to do as a consensus object https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383038/526864

> if another thread jumps in and succeed to modify the *dest first

I think that this premise is flawed because dest can not be allowed to change. The pseudocode should look more like

```
bool compare_and_swap(int *p, int oldval, int newval)
{
  if (*p == oldval) {
      *p = newval;
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

The example that you provided was for a specific implementation that returns the winning processes pid to the losers and only allows the single modification to *dest

> an election protocol can be implemented such that every process checks the result of compare_and_swap against its own PID (= newval)

So compare-and-swap is either implemented with an atomic function/library or uses *cmpxchg* as you surmised

> Do you think that these methods are special methods that directly utilize the hardware to perform atomic operations