# How spin locks are implemented on platforms without CAS instructions?

Tags: c, assembly, locking, cpu-architecture, spinlock

The normal practice is to wrap the CAS instruction in a while loop on platforms that support CAS instructions. But platforms such as SPARC don't have atomic CAS instructions.

Comment: Platforms without atomic CAS provide some other way to do atomic operations, typically LL/SC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional which can be used to implement an atomic exchange or CAS

Comment: A comment on [How are mutexes implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1427368) points this out, but none of the answers do.  Of course CAS isn't the minimal building block; any way of doing Test-and-Set is fine.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383038/412080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPARC v8 (32-bit) and earlier lack CAS, but v9 (64-bit) does have CAS.

For a spin-lock v7 and v8 provide `LDSTUB` which is an atomic-read-modify-write of an unsigned byte, which writes 0xFF.  That does the lock phase of a spin-lock.  An ordinary write of 0 (or anything not 0xFF) will unlock, when using TSO -- for PSO you need an `STBAR` before the write.  [There is also the `SWAP` atomic-read-modify-write, which can be used in the same way.]

To implement CAS (and Fetch-Op) operations on v7/v8 you need an auxiliary spin-lock.

More generally:

- (and as noted in comments) for "modern" devices, if CAS is not supported then some form of "LL/SC" probably is...

  ...and a CAS operation can be synthesized using LL/SC.  [FWIW: LL/SC is more general than CAS and avoids the dreaded ABA that straight CAS is prone to :-(]
- but otherwise, once you have a spin-lock you can simulate most things...

  ...but if the thread holding a spin-lock goes to sleep, everybody gets to wait :-(

Machines (now historic) which provide neither LL/SC nor hardware support for a spin-lock may well have sequentially-consistent memory.  In which case you can implement a spin-lock using Peterson's Algorithm, or Burns', or others'), in software.

Comment: Essentially all modern ISAs that lack a hardware CAS provide [LL/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional).  Both are fully general building blocks for lockless algorithms, not just spinlocks.  stdatomic `compare_exchange_weak` (instead of strong) exists specifically because of LL/SC machines, because it can be implemented without a retry loop, just a handful of instructions.  Anyway, interesting that SPARC v7 specifically has a test-and-set instruction; I hadn't known of an example of an ISA that actually provided just that but not fully general atomic RMWs.